# Can't seem to get bundled files from npm run build

Tags: reactjs, netlify

I'm trying to host my react app on netlify but I'm running in to this error [image] when I try to load the draft page.

When I run my project locally, there isn't a problem but when I do `npm run build` -> `netlify deploy` I get this error when I view the draft page.

Looking in my directory
[image]

[image]

I can see that the files are there but for some reason netlify isn't finding the files. It can be found inside `build/static/css/main...` and `build/static/js/main...`. Does anyone have any advice? THanks!

Answer (score 0):

Figured out the problem. Inside my `package.json`, I was setting `homepage: teslatracker.com` or something like that which was giving me this huge headache. Hope this helps anyone else that has this problem